# Action Sheet problems in iOS 9

Tags: ios9, uialertcontroller

Apple has deprecated the action sheet in iOS 8.3 how do you add an action sheet to my user interface?

I realized Apple's documentation isn't very clear on how to create an action sheet with UIAlertController. So after a little playing around I just wanted to share my code, since I couldn't really find anything useful on Stack Exchange about this topic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem in my iPhone app, with an `UIActionSheet` to ask the user if they wanted to take a photo, or pick an image from their gallery.

[image]

Prior to iOS 9, the following code worked fine:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:@"Take photo", @"Choose Existing", nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

However, in iOS 9, all this does is completely darken the screen, and nothing would appear.

Yeah... thanks Apple.

The solution is to replace the `UIActionSheet` with a `UIAlertController`.

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController
                            alertControllerWithTitle:nil      //  Must be "nil", otherwise a blank title area will appear above our two buttons
                            message:nil
                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction* button0 = [UIAlertAction
                          actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                          style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                          {
                                //  UIAlertController will automatically dismiss the view
                          }];

UIAlertAction* button1 = [UIAlertAction
                          actionWithTitle:@"Take photo"
                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                          {
                              //  The user tapped on "Take a photo"
                              UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController= [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                              imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                              imagePickerController.delegate = self;
                              [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:^{}];
                          }];

UIAlertAction* button2 = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"Choose Existing"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             //  The user tapped on "Choose existing"
                             UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController= [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                             imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                             imagePickerController.delegate = self;
                             [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:^{}];
                         }];

[alert addAction:button0];
[alert addAction:button1];
[alert addAction:button2];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Notice that if you *don't* include a cancel option (an option with the  `UIAlertActionStyleCancel` style), then the action sheet will appear, but tapping anywhere outside of the action sheet *won't* dismiss the menu.

One gotcha:

Even though we've specified that we want this `UIAlertController` to have the style `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`, you need to set the title as `nil`, rather than a blank string, otherwise you get an ugly gap at the top of the window.

[image]

I can't wait to see what perfectly-working code iOS 9.2 will break...

**Update**

My comment: "*However, in iOS 9, all this does is completely darken the screen, and nothing would appear*" was slightly wrong.

Actually, I was opening my `UIActionSheet` while the onscreen keyboard was visible.  And in iOS 9, the keyboard will appear **on top of** your `UIActionSheet`, so you can no longer see your action sheet (!!), but you *do* see that the rest of the screen has turned darker.

With `UIAlertController`, iOS is slightly more user-friendly, as it *hides* the onscreen keyboard before attempting to display the action sheet at the bottom of the screen.  Exactly why Apple doesn't do the same with `UIActionSheets` is beyond me.

(Sigh.)

Please may I go back to using Visual Studio, now..?

**Another update**

Apple has said that UIActionSheets are now "deprecated in iOS 8".

However, if you want to keep using them, on your iOS screens which contain textboxes, then a workaround to this bug, errr, problem, is to add one line of code before displaying your `UIActionSheet`:

```
[self.view endEditing:true];
```

This makes sure the onscreen keyboard is dismissed before displaying your "deprecated" action sheet..

(Sigh.)  If anyone needs me, I'll be in the pub.

Comment: Thanks Derek.  I seem to get trolled a lot on StackOverflow when I post useful replies like this, so it's nice to get some good feedback for once !!

Comment: Hey Mike not a problem! I do have a question that's not related to this thread at all, but do you know if it is possible to build an app where you can unlock your car door through bluetooth? I can't find anything on this, and probably isn't possible, but thought I would ask you.

Comment: @Derek: Sorry, I've absolutely no idea.  But I'd be surprised if it was possible (from a security point of view, if nothing else).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike. I figured the same, but thought to double check. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a snippet of the code I used in my apps for  an action sheet, just in case anyone needed help trying to figure out how to use UIAlertController as an Action Sheet.

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Action Sheet"
                                                                       message:@"This is an action sheet."
                                                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

        UIAlertAction *button1 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Button Title 1" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                            handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                                //code to run once button is pressed
                                                            }];
        UIAlertAction *button2 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Button Title 2" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
            //code to run once button is pressed
        }];

        [alert addAction:button1];
        [alert addAction:button2];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 9 and for iPad I had to add some important changes. May be someone in future might need this.

```
    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Server"
                                                                   message:@"Choose server to point to"
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    UIAlertAction *button1 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Development" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                        //code to run once button is pressed
                                                    }];
    UIAlertAction *button2 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Production" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        //code to run once button is pressed
    }];
    [alert addAction:button1];
    [alert addAction:button2];
    UIPopoverPresentationController *popPresenter = [alert popoverPresentationController];
    popPresenter.sourceView = self.view;
    //To present the actionsheet the bottom of screen
    popPresenter.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.createBtn.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height, self.createBtn.frame.size.width, self.createBtn.frame.size.height);
    alert.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```